# .click on list containing radio - can't select radio directly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I have an unordered list containing radio inputs and labels. When a user clicks on the list item it toggles some info and selects the radio input.

However, due to the above, if the user clicks onto the actual radio input itself, it does not select it, as I guess the click is registered against the radio and not the list item itself?

Is there any cure?

```
    jQuery('#sdmlist li.item').click(function(e) {
       jQuery('#sdmlist li.item address').slideUp();
       jQuery("address",this).slideToggle("slow");
       jQuery("input[type=radio]", this).attr('checked',true);
       var element = jQuery("input[type=radio]", this).val();
       ...
       return false;
    });
```

and some html:

```
     <ul id="sdmlist">
        <li class="item"><input type="radio" name="1" id="1">1 <address>test 123</address></li>
        <li class="item"><input type="radio" name="2" id="2">2 <address>test 23</address></li>
        <li class="item"><input type="radio" name="3" id="3">3 <address>test 3</address></li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: Any demo would be helpful

Comment: Apologies try this: http://jsfiddle.net/4v9R9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is caused by `return false` stopping the default behavior of the click event who has been propagated by then click on the radio. The default behavior of the radio is, of course, the radio beign checked.

Just remove the `return false` and it work : http://jsfiddle.net/4v9R9/2/

Comment: I want the radio checked, but, due to the li click event this does not work when you directly click the radio.

Comment: @BernieDavies Now that i see you fiddle, i understand what you want, brb!

Comment: @BernieDavies Updated, see if it solve your problem.

Comment: If you need the return false, you can detect if the clicked is radio or not and proceed accordingly

Comment: I tried this, and although it makes the radio directly selectable, the slideToggle runs twice on each click of the li item! Though this does not happen in the fiddle?!

Comment: I did this in the end, as suggested: http://jsfiddle.net/4v9R9/ Thank you everyone for your help.